# autocomplete generating routes error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete

I have model `hotel` and its attributes are: `id, hotel_name`

And i have applied autocomplete on home controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :hotel, :hotel_name, :full => true
end
```

and routes are:

```
resources :hotels do
    collection do
      get 'autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name'
    end
end
```

on the view

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <%=autocomplete_field_tag 'hotel_name', '', :autocomplete => autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name_hotels_path %>
  <% end %>
```

But when i type in text field then it producing routing error.

ANd its generating routing error on link

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found  -
>   myhost:3000/%7B:autocomplete=%3E%22/hotels/autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name%22%7D?term=vi""

And when i have decode this URL it look like:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found  -
>   myhost:3000/{:autocomplete=>"/hotels/autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name"}?term=vi"

SO its not generating proper autocomplete URL

Comment: Try just the following: `autocomplete_field_tag 'hotel_name', '', autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name_hotels_path` (the helper is not expection a Hash as 3rd argument but the path)

Comment: Its working but new error I am getting `AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /hotels/autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name
===========================================================================

> The action 'autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name' could not be found for HotelsController`

Comment: You need to add `autocomplete :hotel, :hotel_name, :full => true` to the Hotel controller (will create the actions & routes for /hotels/autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete_field_tag expects you to pass arguments like this:

```
autocomplete_field_tag 'hotel_name', '', autocomplete_hotel_hotel_name_hotels_path
```

The third argument should not be a hash.

---

You also need to specify in your HotelsController that you want autocomplete:

```
class HotelsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :hotel, :hotel_name, :full => true
```